# Error while consuming React file viewer

Tags: reactjs

I have already posted about react-file-viewer, but I've got another problem. I created a new react application with [react docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/installation.html) as reference

And I tried to consume `react-file-viewer` component, like this :

```js
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import FileViewer from 'react-file-viewer'
     
    const file = '../src/test.png'
    
    class App extends Component {
     
      render() {
        return (
      <FileViewer
       fileType="png"
       filePath={file}
        />
        );
      }
      
     
    }
    
    export default App;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

I ahve specified the correct path to the image.
And on the screen I have just a spinner:

[image]

This is what i see in the console logs: 
[image]

Needed help in solving this issue, Thanks in advance.

Comment: could you please share the error logs?

Comment: Hi Jefree, I haven't any error logs .. :(

Comment: i see something with reference to console error, could you just expand it and share it?

Comment: My problem is resolved, I move my file on the racine with the entry point of the app, and it works. It works except for pdf format. Must I create an other post for this problem ?